# How to rewritten rule for c# for GET request example.com/123 redirect to example.com/default.aspx?pid=123 and 123 is dynamic change

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, rules

This is uri http://example.com/xyz where xyz is any number.
i have to redirect this to http://example.com/default.aspx?PID=xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should help you more: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module.

In the IIS Manager create a new rule with:

- action: **Redirect**
- pattern: **^([0-9]{3})**
- redirect URL: **default.aspx?PID={R:1}**

If the xyz will change in length, consider changing the pattern to: **^([0-9]+)**